# How do I show all dataset but with a condition that two values at the same time don't appear?

Tags: laravel

Three datasets for example:

```
#attributes: array:7 [
  "id" => "6"
  "user_id" => "7"
  "offering_id" => "6"
  "offering_type" => "App\Food"
  "created_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
  "updated_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
],

#attributes: array:7 [
  "id" => "7"
  "user_id" => "7"
  "offering_id" => "6"
  "offering_type" => "App\Bike"
  "created_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
  "updated_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
],
 #attributes: array:7 [
  "id" => "6"
  "user_id" => "7"
  "offering_id" => "7"
  "offering_type" => "App\Food"
  "created_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
  "updated_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
]
```

I want to query all data sets but not the combination of

```
"offering_id" => "6"
"offering_type" => "App\Food"
```

My Goal is to get:

```
#attributes: array:7 [
  "id" => "7"
  "user_id" => "7"
  "offering_id" => "6"
  "offering_type" => "App\Bike"
  "created_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
  "updated_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
], [
  "id" => "7"
  "user_id" => "7"
  "offering_id" => "7"
  "offering_type" => "App\Food"
  "created_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
  "updated_at" => "2018-06-16 19:58:38"
]
```

How do I do this?

```
Offer::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('offering_type', '<>', 'App\Food')
          ->where('offering_id', '<>', 6);
})
```

Does not work.

**Additional Informations**

The Model Offer has the relationship

```
public function offering()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

but I don't need this, I just want to query everything out (but I don't need the doubles "offering_id" => "6" "offering_type" => "App\Food" )

Comment: Sorry for the title. English is not my mother tongue and I miss the words for the title...

Comment: Instead of 'App\Food' you should put food_id

Comment: @Metalik you mean  "where('offering_type', '<>', food_id??)" why ? I'm sorry I don't get it

Comment: App\Food is a relation. you should pass id of food which is integer on where.

Comment: Could you post the code that deffines the relation to `offering` from your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're looking for - I assume you want to list all values except the ones that have both `offering_type = "App\Food"` and `offering_id = 6`. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

The following should do the trick:

```
Offer::where(function ($query) {
  $query->where('offering_type', '<>', 'App\Food')
        ->orWhere('offering_id', '<>', 6);
})
```